# Adding close on click out of modal throws a few warnings

Tags: reactjs

Before creating the question I searched for this issue but the related questions don't work for my issue.

I have a Modal component where I want to capture when the user clicks the backdrop or the modal (when it's displayed it takes 100% width/heigth of the window like the backdrop).

When the user clicks, no matter where the clicked is done, and `handleMouseUp` is fired I get the warning:

```
Warning: Rendering <Context.Consumer.Provider> is not supported and will be removed in a future major release. 
Did you mean to render <Context.Provider> instead?
```

I don't know why the warning is thrown becuase I'm not using any context in the component. If I remove the `onMouseEvent` the warning is not thrown. I can confirm the warning appears when I add the event.

On the other side I'm getting a different warning related to `ref`:

```
Warning: div: 'ref' is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in 'undefined' being returned. 
If you need to access the same value within the child component, you should pass it as a different prop
```

I looked for this warning and I don't understand why it's thrown as I don't have any additional component using `ref` or passing it as a prop...

This is the code I have for the component.

```
export default function Modal({ children, isVisible, hide, ...props }) {
  const modalRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (modalRef && isVisible) {
      modalRef.current!.focus();
    }

    document.body.classList.toggle('noOverflow', isVisible);
  }, [isVisible, modalRef]);

  const handleMouseUp = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target, modalRef.current);
  };

  return (
    isVisible &&
    createPortal(
      <>
        <div
          className={styles.backdrop}
          onClick={hide}
        ></div>

        <div
          className={styles.modal}
          tabIndex={-1}
          ref={modalRef}
          onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
          onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
          {...props}
        >
          <div className={`${styles.content} ${className}`}>
            <div className={styles.header}>
              {allowClose && (
                <Icon
                  name="close-o"
                  onClick={hide}
                />
              )}
            </div>

            <div className={styles.body}>{children}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>,
      document.body,
    )
  );
}
```

I tried to wrap the function into a `useCallback` hook but the warning is still thrown.

I tried to reproduce the warnings in a [StackBlitz project](https://stackblitzstarters4p6h8d-wr15--3000--6843a59c.local-corp.webcontainer.io/) but I'm not able to do it...

Comment: Those seem like odd errors to come out of the code you've included, I think we'd need to see a [mre] to help resolve this.

Comment: @DBS I updated the post adding a sample on StackBlitz, unfortunatelly the warnings are not thrown, that confuses me a bit more...

Comment: That would imply that the issue isn't caused by the code you're looking at. Have you added any libraries that might be broken? I would have another look at the call stack in the warning message and see if you can track down exactly where it's occurring.